# Android detect on close event in custom Preference class

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a preference class in which I have some logic implemented. I want to be able to detect when that preference is closed so I can disconnect google API client.

My custom preference class. Everything works fine but when I close the preference and open it again, it shows an error that API client with that ID already exists.

My preference class represents the whole preference screen which has location autocomplete text editor.

**preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Notifications"
    android:key="pref_key_storage_settings">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:key="pref_enable_notifications"
        android:title="News notifications"
        android:defaultValue="true" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="pref_confirms_needed"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:title="@string/pref_confirmsNeeded"
        android:defaultValue="0"
        android:dialogMessage="Enter minimum number of confirms news should have for you to be notified about it."
        android:summary="You will be notified only for news that have higher number of confirms than the number you set here." />
    <Preference
        android:key="pref_location_screen"
        android:persistent="false"
        android:title="Notification range" />
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I didn't show any code as  I want to keep it simple. If you need it let me know!

**EDIT**

I added code

**LocationPreference.xml**

```
public class LocationPreference extends Preference implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final String TAG = "LocationPreference";
    private Context mContext;
    private PlaceAutocompleteAdapter mLocationAutocompleteAdapter;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final LatLngBounds LAT_LNG_BOUNDS = new LatLngBounds(
        new LatLng(-40, -168), new LatLng(71, 136));
    private View autocompleteSearch;

    // widgets
    private AutoCompleteTextView mSearchText;

    public LocationPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.location_preference);

        mContext = context;
    }

    public LocationPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
    super(context, attrs);
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.location_preference);

        mContext = context;
    }

    public LocationPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)     {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.location_preference);

        mContext = context;
    }


    private void init() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(mContext)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage((AppCompatActivity) mContext,this)
                .build();
        }

        mLocationAutocompleteAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(
            mContext, mGoogleApiClient, LAT_LNG_BOUNDS, null);
        mSearchText.setAdapter(mLocationAutocompleteAdapter);

        mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                    || i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                    || keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    //geoLocate();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.stopAutoManage((AppCompatActivity) mContext);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        super.onCreateView(parent);
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (autocompleteSearch == null) {
            autocompleteSearch = li.inflate(R.layout.location_preference, parent, false);
            mSearchText = autocompleteSearch.findViewById(R.id.location_pref_input);
            mSearchText.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);
            init();
        }

        return autocompleteSearch;
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //hideSoftKeyboard();
            Log.d(TAG, "OnItemClick()");
            final AutocompletePrediction item = mLocationAutocompleteAdapter.getItem(i);
            final String placeId = item.getPlaceId();

            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                   .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
        }
    };



    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResult()");
            if(!places.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: Place query did not complete successfully: " + places.getStatus().toString());
                places.release();
                return;
            }
            final Place place = places.get(0);

                persistString(CommonUtils.latLngToStr(place.getViewport().getCenter().latitude,
                place.getViewport().getCenter().longitude));

            SharedPreferences preferences =     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            Map<String, ?> allEntries = preferences.getAll();
            for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
                Log.d(TAG, entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
            }

            places.release();

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**

I think my best bet is to simply check if Google Api client exists.

Comment: Code is an absolute requirement for specific problems!

Comment: I agree, but isn't this a general question? Basically, I want to know if there is any alternative to onClose or onPause for Preference class?

Comment: That's not code, that's XML. There's no way to know what could be causing the error without code.

Answer (score 0):

Really need to see your code and have a clearer idea of what you are trying to do.

But if you are trying to close everything down when the user closes the preferences, essentially going back to your app main screen, you could try disconnecting your google API client in the <strike>onBackPressed activity calllback</strike>

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();

    // Do your stuff here.
}
```

Actually, you cold go deeper and do it in the on Destroy callback which fires after onBackPressed

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

    // Do your stuff here.
}
```

Which should be the last callback fired before coming back to your app activity.

Oh, sorry, for a preference, try the onPrepareForRemoval callback

```
@Override
public void onPrepareForRemoval()
{
    super.onPrepareForRemoval();

    // Close the google api here.
}
```

Then if that did not work, try moving the Google API closure/disconnect to the PreferenceActvity onDestroy callback.

I'd personally recommend refactoring the code to use a PreferenceFragment rather than a Preference.

Comment: Yes, that would work in Activity class. I have Preference class. I posted the whole class. Let me know if you need something else maybe. I just want to be able to detect that in LocationPreference.class

Comment: @nodrus Changed my answer for a Preference class, see if that helps.

Comment: Ok I added that code and tested it. I still get the same error. I put breakpoints into that callback and it doesn't get fired at all. I think the problem might be because of this preference is inside of a fragment.

Comment: @nodrus I updated my answer, have a look at the bottom of it.

Comment: Yeah, I think refactoring my best bet here! Thanks!